# Fixing an LED night light circuit

Tags: led, resistors

I bought an LED night light that's powered by three AAA batteries. At first it was super bright (too bright!) but then faded and finally went dead after just a week. It seemed to me that it didn't have an adequate current limiting resistor so I opened it up. It's simply 8 LEDs in series with a resistor, 3 AAA batteries and a switch. 
[image: bare nightlight]
The resistor is strange since it appears to be red-red-gold-gold banding and I don't know what to make of gold in the third position. 
[image: nightlight resistor]
My question is, do you think it was the resistor that caused it to burn out so fast, and if so, what would be an appropriate replacement?

Comment: https://www.digikey.ca/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-resistor-color-code-4-band

Comment: Have you checked/replaced the batteries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each White 5mm LED is rated about 65mW at 3.1V@20mA with an ESR of approx 15 Ohms intersecting with 2.8V.

Thus 8 parallel LEDs have an ESR of 15/8~=2 ohms. The fixed part appears have gold indicating a decimal point between Red-Red or 2.2 Ohms .

Thus current at 4.5V to 2.9V to a load defined as 2.8V +(15/8+2.2)If=Vbat

Thus If =( Vbat-2.8V ) /  4 Ohms

For Vbat =4.5 , If= 53mA / LED. !!
For Vbat =4.0 , If = 38mA / LED !
For Vbat = 3.5, If = 22mA / LED ok.
For Vbat = 3.1, If =  2.8 mA/ LED dim.

So power consumption for average at 4V is 1.2 Watts and 3 cell’s with est 3* 1.8Wh @ 0.5A  might give 4 hours really too bright then a few days dim to dead.

Conclusion :

bad match of battery to load.  Increasing R to two 2.2 R’s to share heat or 4.4 reduces power drain, reduces efficiency  but reduces the initial current giving slightly more time.  Maybe 2 weeks vs 1.

Chalk it up to a poor design.

Comment: I bet you could smell the epoxy of the 2.2 Ohm resistor the 1st night.

Comment: Is there a good mix of battery and resistor that would give this 8 LED panel a decent lifetime?

Comment: Do you have any Li-ion 18650 cells and charger?  It will reduce initial excess brightness but has the about same capacity at this high load in Wh (watt-hours) as 3 AA's then get a bunch online and swap out every week before they go dead. or a better light.

Comment: Changing the resistor value does not change the efficiency.   Reducing the current by 50% will increase lifespan of an alkaline by more than 2X.  Lower discharge rate significantly increases capacity of alkaline batteries.   The current batteries are AAA not AA.  You did not make it very clear to replace the 3 AAA with a single 18650.

Comment: Incorrect.  It changes efficiency from I² R=Ploss now doubling with R but other fixed ESR's in battery and LED's remain ~ same.

Comment: But I agree I should have said only 3.7V or so

Comment: Work it out.  The supply voltage remains the same, the LED voltage remains the same, and the drop across the resistor remains the same.  Therefor the power ratio (efficiency) LED/Total must also remain the same.  The current is reduced so I² is also reduced and R is increased.  The efficiency is 67% if Vf = 3V and supply = 4.5V no matter what the current or resistor value.

Comment: I already did. The ESR's of LED equiv being 2 and Rs=2.2 being equal , adding another 2 2 Ohms means Vf variation cuts reduces by 50% so Rs voltage drop increases which was assumed constant in yours.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/y7n5rn3r

Answer (score 2):

You did not say how many hours per day, but still battery powered LEDs drawing the amount of current these do, will not last long.  Alkaline is a poor battery to use due to its steep discharge curve and low cutoff voltage of 0.8V.

The LEDs have low efficacy (lumens/watt), meaning they do not give enough light for the amount of power used.  A higher efficacy LED requires less current (and power).

With a supply of 4.5V, estimated LED Vf of 3.0V, and a resistor of 2.2Ω you are drawing 682 mA.

[image]

---

This is a heavy load for AAA batteries.  It reduces the lifespan (capacity) as shown below.

[image]
Source:  [ENERGIZER E92 Alkaline AAA Datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/e92.pdf)

---

It couldn't have been bright for too many hours.
This graph represents about a 300 mA draw at 4.5V.

[image]
Source:  [ENERGIZER E92 Alkaline AAA Datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/e92.pdf)

---

> Is there a good mix of battery and resistor that would give this 8 LED
>   panel a decent lifetime?

NiMH batteries have a very flat discharge curve and comes in the same size as an AAA.  Notice how the voltage has dropped to only 1.1V near the end of life.  The nominal voltage 1.2V to cutoff 1.1 is only 7% change in lifespan voltage.  This is advantageous for a more constant brightness over the lifespan of the battery.

[image]
Source: [Panasonic AAA NiMH](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidsa/files/downloads/files/panasonic-bk70aaaj-datasheet.pdf)

---

An 18650 Li-ion cell is 18 mm in diameter vs. 10.5 mm for an AAA.
An 18650 Li-ion cell is 65 mm in length vs. 44 mm for an AAA.
Li-ion has an 11% change in lifespan voltage but has greater capacity per volume.

[image]
[Datasheet 18650 LI-ion battery Panasonic Li-ion NCR18650PF](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf2/ACA4000/ACA4000C50.pdf)

---

To reduce the load you could do the following:

Best would be to use higher efficacy LEDs.
You could remove a couple of the LED as they are wired in parallel.
You could try increasing the resistor to between 6Ω and 10Ω

**It would be best if you used a 3.3V-5V DC power supply.**